# ASUS Z170-A motherboard sound clipping issue

Tags: audio, motherboard, sound-card

I have recently built a PC with Asus Z170-A mobo and about a week ago the sound went all of a sudden really bad. When I set the volume in OS to a higher level (30% or more) and have the volume in an application on 100%, the sound gets clipped pretty heavily.

When the volume is set to approx. 15% and to a low level in an application as well and amplified on my speakers, it doesn't clip but a quite noticeable noise get mixed in. Weird is that the noise is heard only with sound when there is nothing playing it is quiet.

It is not OS related as I'm running dual boot Win 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 and the issue is exactly the same in both. I tried reinstalling, rolling back drivers, using Realtek drivers without effect.
I was thinking I might have messed something in bios, but resetting to defaults changed nothing (And I haven't found any settings related to sound card there anyway).

The soundcard on the board is: Realtek® ALC892

Any hope to get this fixed on my own?

Comment: What type of device are you using to output audio?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I'm using regular speakers with subwoofer outputting through 3.5mm jack.

Comment: Do you get the same results with different devices?

Comment: Yes, I've tried everything, the problem was with the motherboard, I got it replaced shortly after I discovered the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For all we have audio problems (click a pops) Asus Z170-A when CPU load is high, try this:
go to BIOS / AI Tweaker / AI Overclock, change XMP to Auto and all options under this to Auto also.

This fix all audio problems for me when high CPU or GPU loads.